# Find all elements with a specific CSS property

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to find elements in a webpage that contain the CSS property `overflow-y: scroll` or `overflow-y: auto`. Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//*[contains(@style,'overflow-y: scroll')] | //*[contains(@style,'overflow-y: auto')]")
```

This will find me all the elements that have a style attribute with vertical overflow set to scroll/auto.

However, this won't find me elements that have this attribute set in their external CSS. To solve this, the first and rather naive solution that has come to my mind is to iterate over the DOM and check each element's CSS. Does anyone know a faster solution, possibly with Xpaths?

Comment: +1 for a good question. Is it possible for you to access that external css file? If yes, you can parse it using a robust regular expression to get the tag names or id or class of all the desired elements that are assoicated with a specifc style. Once you have that information, it is easy to create xpath(s) and use them in conjunction.

Comment: I need this algorithm to work on any website rather than a particular one. If it is possible to get the CSS files of any website in a programmatical way inside a program, then I could definitely use regex. Is this possible?